# Return row counts for field that appears more than x times

Tags: sql, t-sql

In my SQL table, I'd like to find the state codes that appear more than 300 times and also what the total row counts are for records containing each respective state code. More than a bit rusty on my SQL (plus it's 8am on a Monday...) and this is what i have so far:

```
SELECT StateCode
FROM ZipCodeTerritory
HAVING COUNT(StateCode) > 300
```

Comment: You cannot use `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT StateCode, Count(*) As StateCodeCount
FROM ZipCodeTerritory
Group By StateCode
HAVING COUNT(*) > 300
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT StateCode, count(StateCode)
FROM ZipCodeTerritory
GROUP BY StateCode
HAVING COUNT(StateCode) > 300
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT StateCode, count(*)
FROM ZipCodeTerritory
GROUP BY StateCode
HAVING count(*) > 300
```